# How can I enable keyboard backlight on Sony Vaio pro with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, vaio, sony, backlight, 13.10

How can I enable keyboard backlight on Sony Vaio pro with Ubuntu 13.10?

I have already tried setting the bit in `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight` with

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
```

and when saving the file I can see the bit has changed, but my keyboard still stays off.

Has anyone else had this problem, and found a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Check also `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight_timeout` where:

- `0`(default) = 10 secs
- `1` = 30 secs,
- `2` = 60 secs and
- `3` = unlimited.

Or possibly use a `/etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf` file with:

```
options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=2
```