# Keyboard backlight not working on Ubuntu 17.0 on a Sony VAIO

Tags: keyboard, 17.04, vaio, sony, keyboard-backlight

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my rather old Sony VAIO. When it's booting, the keyboard backlight enables when I touch a key and disables itself after a certain timeout. However, the moment Ubuntu starts, the backlights stop enabling, so keeps disabled.

How do I make this keyboard stay enabled or at least enable itself on keypress?

Comment: Please check if this solves your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/345475/how-can-i-enable-keyboard-backlight-on-sony-vaio-pro-with-ubuntu-13-10