# Keyboard backlight not working - Sony SVT15115CXS (18.04.1 LTS)

Tags: keyboard, backlight, vaio, sony

I have tried many things to get the keyboard backlight working on my laptop, to no avail.

`lsmod` shows the `sony-laptop` module. When I get `modinfo` for `sony-laptop`, I see parameters `kbd_backlight` & `kbd_backlight_timeout`.

I've tried `sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1`, which I saw as an answer somewhere else, but that did not work.

Note, the backlight works during boot, but turns off once Ubuntu loads.

I would forever be grateful for a solution; I'm in the dark at the moment.

EDIT: I tried `sudo cat` on the `sony-laptop.ko` file and it returned (among other things) `no backlight keyboard found`. I'm thinking it can't find the backlight on my keyboard--not sure why.

Comment: Having the same issue on Gen3 Thinkpad X1 Carbon running 18 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable keyboard backlight on sony vaio pro with ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345475/how-can-i-enable-keyboard-backlight-on-sony-vaio-pro-with-ubuntu-13-10)